# How do I render a child component within an iframe in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe

So I want to show the user a preview of what an email will look like before it's sent out. To avoid styles from leaking from the parent page into the preview, I've decided to use an iframe. I want the preview to update in real time as the user enters form details.

How would I render a component within an iframe so that its props update automatically when the parent form is updated? This is the code I have so far:

this is the html:

```
<template>
    <div id="confirmation">
        <h2>Give a gift</h2>
        <form @submit.prevent="checkout()">
            <div class="date-section">
                <label class="wide">Send</label>
                <input type="radio" name="sendLater" v-model="sendLater" required :value="false">
                <span>Now</span>
                <input type="radio" name="sendLater" v-model="sendLater" required :value="true">
                <span style="margin-right: 5px;">Later: </span>
                <date-picker :disabled="!sendLater" v-model="date" lang="en" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Recipient Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="custom-text"  v-model="form.email" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Recipient Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="custom-text"  v-model="form.name" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Add a personal message</label>
                <textarea v-model="form.message" />
            </div>
            <p class="error" v-if="error">Please enter a valid date.</p>
            <div class="button-row">
                <button class="trumpet-button" type="submit">Next</button>
                <button class="trumpet-button gray ml10" type="button" @click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <iframe id="preview-frame">
            <preview-component :form="form" :sender-email="senderEmail" :term="term" />
        </iframe>
    </div>
</template>
```

here is the js (note: PreviewComponent is the actual preview that will be rendered in the iframe):

```
export default {
    name: 'ConfirmationComponent',
    components: {
        DatePicker,
        PreviewComponent
    },
    props: {
        term: {
            required: true,
            type: Object
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                name: null,
                email: null,
                message: null,
                date: null
            },
            date: null,
            sendLater: false,
            error: false
        }
    },
    computed: {
        senderEmail() {
            // utils comes from a separate file called utils.js
            return utils.user.email || ''
        }
    },
    watch: {
        'form.name'(val) {
            this.renderIframe()
        },
        'form.email'(val) {
            this.renderIframe()
        }
    },
    methods: {
        renderIframe() {
            if (this.form.name != null && this.form.email != null) {
                console.log('rendering iframe')
                // not sure what to do here......
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

I've tried all sorts of things but what seems to be the hardest is setting the props of the preview-component properly. Any help you all can give would be appreciated.

Comment: This is easy if you are using vuex. Data will update in real time all and you can access data across the page, you just need to do is to show and hide the `preview-component` when necessary.

Comment: oh gotcha. is vuex data from the parent page accessible within the iframe? that seems like it could work if that is possible

Comment: so i got vuex working properly, now the problem seems to be getting the component html and styles into the iframes #document property. for some reason the component is being rendered outside the document....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as posted in one of the comments, Vuex works perfectly for this.

I also ended up creating a custom "IFrame" component that renders whatever you have inside its slot in an iframe.

Here is my Vuex store:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        form: {
            name: null,
            email: null,
            message: null
        },
        senderEmail: null,
        term: null,
        styles: null
    },
    mutations: {
        updateForm(state, form) {
            state.form = form
        },
        updateEmail(state, email) {
            state.senderEmail = email
        },
        updateTerm(state, term) {
            state.term = term
        },
        stylesChange(state, styles) {
            state.styles = styles
        }
    }
})
```

my IFrame component:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { store } from '../../store'

export default {
    name: 'IFrame',
    data() {
        return {
            iApp: null,

        }
    },
    computed: {
        styles() {
            return this.$store.state.styles
        }
    },
    render(h) {
        return h('iframe', {
            on: {
                load: this.renderChildren
            }
        })
    },
    watch: {
        styles(val) {
            const head = this.$el.contentDocument.head

            $(head).html(val)
        }
    },
    beforeUpdate() {
        this.iApp.children = Object.freeze(this.$slots.default)
    },
    methods: {
        renderChildren() {
            const children = this.$slots.default
            const body = this.$el.contentDocument.body

            const el = document.createElement('div') // we will mount or nested app to this element
            body.appendChild(el)

            const iApp = new Vue({
                name: 'iApp',
                store,
                data() {
                    return {
                        children: Object.freeze(children)
                    }
                },
                render(h) {
                    return h('div', this.children)
                }
            })

            iApp.$mount(el)

            this.iApp = iApp
        }
    }
}
```

finally here is how data is passed to the PreviewComponent from the ConfirmationComponent:

```
export default {
    name: 'ConfirmationComponent',
    mounted() {
        this.$store.commit('updateEmail', this.senderEmail)
        this.$store.commit('updateTerm', this.term)
    },
    watch: {
        'form.name'(val) {
            this.updateIframe()
        },
        'form.email'(val) {
            this.updateIframe()
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateIframe() {
            this.$store.commit('updateForm', this.form)
        }
    }
}
```

then lastly the actual PreviewComponent:

```
import styles from '../../../templates/styles'

export default {
    name: 'PreviewComponent',
    mounted() {
        this.$store.commit('stylesChange', styles)
    },
    computed: {
        redemption_url() {
            return `${window.config.stitcher_website}/gift?code=`
        },
        custom_message() {
            if (this.form.message) {
                let div = document.createElement('div')

                div.innerHTML = this.form.message

                let text = div.textContent || div.innerText || ''

                return text.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>')
            }
            return null
        },
        form() {
            return this.$store.state.form
        },
        term() {
            return this.$store.state.term
        },
        senderEmail() {
            return this.$store.state.senderEmail
        }
    }
}
```

hopefully this will help somebody.

Comment: Hi @janedoe could you please create a working demo for us. understanding it is difficult for me.